# Dynamic Slider

Tags: javascript

I need to integrate a dynamic slider into a webpage which sould have a dragable pointer on it.As it is dragged the value on a corresponding box should also change.There should be no upper limit to the slider.It should have numbers ranging on its body,which should change automatically when the pointer is dragged at runtime.I mean,as it is dragged to the higher end,the number's range should dynamically change from say,10-20 to 100-200.Also,as soon as the pointer is left at any particular point of the slider,it should return back to the orignal position,from where it was dragged,leaving the number's range changed.
Can anyone please help me with this issue?Any framework (jquery,dojo,script.aculo.us,etc.)is welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery ui has the [slider()](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7.1/Slider) that will get you far on the way. With it you can create a slider and you can use the "slide" option to display where on the slider scale you are very easily. You just need to set "min" and "max" values and jQuery will do the calculation. All you would need then, would be to attach an event to reset the slider's position when the user is done sliding and you would be set.